# RegEx: different initials format

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this piece of code to get the initials of the person's full name:

```
var name = "John Smith"; // for an example
var initials = name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
initials = ((initials.shift() || '') + (initials.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
// initials then returns "JS"
```

Now I need my initials to return the first letter of the first name and three letters of the last name ("JSMI" in the example above).

What should I alter in my regex in order to do that?

Also, if person would have two names (for example "John Michael Smith"), I need to get "JMSMI" as a result...

Any other solutions are welcome!

Comment: what if last name is less than 3 letters?

Comment: @tsh I'm pretty sure there won't be any in my case, but ideally it should return the full last name then (1 or 2 letters)

Comment: "John Michael Smith" has three names, not two.

Comment: @torazaburo I meant two first names :)

Comment: Try `var res = name.match(/\b\w{1,3}(?=\w*$)|\b\w/g).map(x => x.toUpperCase()).join("");`

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I get a syntax error on the `=>` part using your example

Comment: `name.match(/\b\w{1,3}(?=\w*$)|\b\w/g).map(function (x) {return  x.toUpperCase();}).join("")`

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/jfec1csg/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!! Exactly what I was looking for :) Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: The `=>` arrow function is ES6 browsers compatible (should work in  Chorme and FF), but does not work with ES5 browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a `\b\w{1,3}(?=\w*$)` alternative to your existing regex at the start to match 1 to 3 words chars in the last word of the string.

```js
var name = "John Michael Smith"; //John Smith" => JSMI
var res = name.match(/\b\w{1,3}(?=\w*$)|\b\w/g).map(function (x) {return x.toUpperCase()}).join("");
console.log(res);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fMs9D/1).

**Regex details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\w{1,3}` - 1 to 3 word chars (ASCII letters, digits or `_`)
- `(?=\w*$)` -  a positive lookahead requiring 0+ word chars followed with the end of string position
- `|`  - or
- `\b\w` - a word char at the start of a word.

I tried to avoid capturing groups (and used the positive lookahead) to make the JS code necessary to post-process the results shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`Array#split()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZgavQlb_TAhXGLY8KHYPFBCAQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit&usg=AFQjCNGVGuY9DfI9VAkeEZ1pZRBFS8cyUg&sig2=fKkM4ydBpLtyJXBHfwikyA) , [`substring()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs7_Tblb_TAhWLMI8KHb0dBnAQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_substring.asp&usg=AFQjCNEUM3iTrVoa9uCyGsjsP90GkKiLjg&sig2=uEFN-3iX9frHK-W-mt2tug) and [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5yIG3lr_TAhUJuY8KHenTDfkQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=S4SBcui-uL4Z25m94RQSYg)

1. first you need split the string with space.
2. And get the single letter `array[n-1]` using sustring,
3. Then get the 3 letter on final argument of array
4. Map function iterate each word of your string

```js
function reduce(a){
var c= a.split(" ");
var res = c.map((a,b) => b < c.length-1 ? a.substring(0,1) : a.substring(0,3))
return res.join("").toUpperCase()
}

console.log(reduce('John Michael Smith'))
console.log(reduce('John Smith'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split()`  and `substr()`  to easily do this.

### EDIT

Updated code to reflect the middle initial etc

```js
function get_initials(name) {
  var parts = name.split(" ");

  var initials = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (i < (parts.length - 1)) {
      initials += parts[i].substr(0, 1);
    } else {
      initials += parts[i].substr(0, 3);
    }
  }
  return initials.toUpperCase();

}

console.log(get_initials("John Michael Smith"));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm familiar with javascript, so I know I can write a function like this, but I also need to check if person has multiple first names, also if the last name is at least 3 characters long, so I would end up with a pretty big function :) This is a regex question, just to see if it can do it in one line :) Thanks anyway! +1

Comment: @GintasK  not really that complex -- and you can write out the code  like this at first, then use that to model your regex expression ;)

Comment: @GintasK what if they only have one name?  Or they have  a name like  Jon David Robert Thomas, then the regex may not work..

Comment: Just tested @WiktorStribiżew 's regex and it works for any number of names

Comment: @GintasK try this name:   "John Worthington, Jr."

Answer (score 2):

You may want use `String.prototype.replace` to drop following letters:

This regexp will match first 1 (or 3 for last name) letters in a word, and only keep it.

```
'John Smith'.replace(/(?:(\w)\w*\s+)|(?:(\w{3})\w*$)/g, '$1$2').toUpperCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents with a reducer :)

```js
function initials(name) {
  return name.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, item, index, array) {
    var chars = index === array.length - 1 ? 3 : 1;
    acc += item.substr(0, chars).toUpperCase();
    return acc;
  }, '')
}

console.log(initials('John'));
console.log(initials('John Michael'));
console.log(initials('John Michael Smith'));
```

Comment: Your reducer seems to be nothing more than an awkward way to do `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const name = "John Michael Smith";

const initials = name.toUpperCase().split(/\s+/)
  .map((x, i, arr) => x.substr(0, i === arr.length - 1 ? 3 : 1))
  .join('');

console.log(initials);
```